# get current user role and redirect to specific action

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-validation, redirecttoaction

I'm trying to create different redirection in my Login Action Result in the sense that if a user logs in and is in a Role redirect to a specific view

E.g. If a receptionist logs in redirect to `RedirectToAction("Index", "Booking");

I've tried a logic but it doesn't work...below is what i've done.

```
private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (User.IsInRole("Doctor"))
        {
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Patient");
            }
        }

        if (User.IsInRole("Receptionist"))
        {
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("PatientBooking", "BooKing");
            }
        }

        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("GeneralSearch", "Search");
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**
Below is how i'm calling the method in the Login ActionResult

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var loginbusiness = new LoginBusiness();
            var result = await loginbusiness.LogUserIn(model, AuthenticationManager);

            if (result)
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }

            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

But it doesn't work for me any ideas for this ???

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: It doesn't go through the validation process it just redirects to the return RedirectToAction("GeneralSearch", "Search"); method @ElenaDBA

Comment: I think the problem is your conditional logic

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
{
    if (User.IsInRole("Doctor"))
    {
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Patient");
        }
    }

    else if (User.IsInRole("Receptionist"))
    {
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("PatientBooking", "BooKing");
        }
    }
else
{
    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
    {
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("GeneralSearch", "Search");
    }
 }
 }
```

Comment: Okay let me try this logic now @ElenaDBA

Comment: It's still giving the same thing... @ElenaDBA

Comment: Obviously the User role is neither "Doctor" nor "Receptionist". Did you try debugging to see what it is? It could be as simple as letter casing

Comment: The roles do exist in that format, i've edited my original code to add the login actionresult @ElenaDBA

Comment: I think it doesn't authenticate the User just yet. @ElenaDBA cause on putting a break on the line of code it returns this   ( IsAuthenticated = false )

Comment: then the problem has got to be where you are authenticating

Comment: I finally got it to work, check the logic I posted thanks for your cooperation @ElenaDBA

Answer (score 0):

After much study I got a logic that works just fine...

```
var context = new DataContext();

            var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
            var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
            if (result)
            {
                var user = userManager.FindByName(model.UserName);

                if (userManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "Receptionist"))
                {
                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
                    {
                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("PatientBooking", "BooKing");
                    }

                }
            }
```

This works !!!

Comment: : ) I know I must have given u a headache lol...wasn't intended @ElenaDBA